# How to increment or dicrement from current index within the total

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping a number between `0` to `total` what i have. the thing is, it need to create from `currentIndex` and it should not more that `total` same way i need to dicreement the value from `currentIndex` but not less than `0`.

I tried but nothing come handy.
here is my try:

```
var total = 6;
var currentIndex = 3;
var num = 0;
function add(amount) {
   return num = (num + total - currentIndex + amount) % total + 1

}


$('a').click(function(e){
    var num = e.target.className == 'prev' ? -1 : 1;
    var result = add(num)+currentIndex;
    console.log(result);
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7b7ngrs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think simpler, but you were on the right track:

```js
var total = 6;
var currentIndex = 3;
var num = 0;
function add(amount) {
   currentIndex=((currentIndex+amount%total)+total)%total;
}


$('a').click(function(e){
    var num = e.target.className == 'prev' ? -1 : 1;
    add(num);
    console.log(currentIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>  <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
```

This will loop between 0 and 5 inclusive.

Comment: In previous link click, i am getting `-1,-2,-3,-4` like so. i need after 0 again 5,4,3..

Comment: sorry js modulo acts funny, fixed it